Customize Client to distinguish client from agency
I want to start build an ecommerce site for my company, i need to create a login for simple clientes and a login for other agencies and companies, with custom informations and many employees, i need to know this company to give him a small discount.
Did you think i need to create custom module for agency and register every employee as client?
Or there is a simple solution in craft cms?

A good way to have different rules apply to different users are User Groups. You can create one user group for regular clients and one for your agency clients. Then you can offer different prices and functionality based on which groups a user is in.
If you're building your E-commerce site with Craft Commerce, you can offer discounts based on the user group.
